# Text between substring and first dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text, and I need to replace some text within the original one.
So, for examample:

**Original Text:**
Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10  . Construction year: 1974. Adjustments made for hpi (4%), area (-5.00%). Closed price after adjustments: 1,022.07 €/m2.

I need to find replace what's between the substring "Construction year:" and the next dot (.) after this substring.

**Final Expected Text:**
Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10  . New construction year: 2010. Adjustments made for hpi (4%), area (-5.00%). Closed price after adjustments: 1,022.07 €/m2.

**Incorrect Final Text I´m getting**
I am getting the last dot (.), nor the next one, so everything between the substring and the last dot (.) is changed. Obtaining this:

Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10  . New construction year: 2010.

var new_generated_comparable_comment = generated_comparable_comment.replace(/(Catastral Reference: ).*.([^.]*)/, 'Catastral Reference: ' + value + ').');

Thank you.

Comment: This is the code in javascript, with which I´m trying to get the solution: var new_generated_comparable_comment = generated_comparable_comment.replace(/(Construction year:).*.([^.]*)/, 'Construction year: ' + value + '.');

Comment: Not sure you why you try a regex with "Catastral Reference: " when you really want to find "Construction year". Is it me or are those terms completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you used `(Construction year:).*.([^.]*)` captures *Construction year:* in a capturing group. Then the `.*` matches any character except a newline 0+ times and will match until the end of the string. After that it matches 1 time any character and 0+ times not a dot so all after *Construction year:* will stay being matched.

If you want to replace the year after `Construction year:`, you could use the capturing group `$1` followed by what you want to replace the match with. Following the capturing group, you could match not a dot `[^.]+`.

```
(Construction year: )[^.]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KHNyOe/1)

You could add the global flag `/g` at the end of the regex for multiple matches.

```js
const regex = /(Construction year: )[^.]+/;
const str = `Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10 . Construction year: 1974. Adjustments made for hpi (4%), area (-5.00%). Closed price after adjustments: 1,022.07 €/m2.`;
const subst = `$12010`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```js
     var original = 'Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10 . Construction year: 1974. Adjustments made for hpi (4%), area (-5.00%). Closed price after adjustments: 1,022.07 €/m2.'
     var newYear = 2010
     var updated = original.replace(/Construction year: \d{4}./, `Construction year: ${newYear}`)
     console.log(updated)
```

Answer (score 1):

With help of `replace` you can do like this

```js
let str =`Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10 . Construction year: 1974. Adjustments made for hpi (4%), area (-5.00%). Closed price after adjustments: 1,022.07 €/m2.`

let op = str.replace(/(Construction year: )([^.]+)/g,"$1"+"2010" )

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good time to use `String.replace()` with some `Regex`.

Comment: That´s what I´m actually trying: var new_generated_comparable_comment = generated_comparable_comment.replace(/(Construction year:).*.([^.]*)/, 'Construction year: ' + value + '.');

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy mate, just use `replace` with the simple regex `/Construction year:.*?\./`!
You will catch everything from `Construction year:` to the next dot, whatever this is!

```js
const text = 'Flat sold with annexes. Transaction date 01-01-2014 carried out in same area. INMACULADA, 10 . Construction year: 1974. Adjustments made for hpi (4%), area (-5.00%). Closed price after adjustments: 1,022.07 €/m2.'

function replace(year) {
  return text.replace(/Construction year:.*?\./, 'New construction year: '+year+'.')
}

console.log(replace('2017'));
```